# Cancelling an Async Task When TextBox Text Changed Then Restart It

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I've .NET app and there are DataGridView and TextBox on my GUI. What I want to do is when user change TextBox text, update DataGridView where cells contains this text. But this search should run as async task because if it's not, it causes freeze on GUI. Everytime when user changed TextBox text, my app should cancel if another search task running and rerun it again to search according to new search values.  Here is my code;

```cs
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
private async void TextBox1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    cts.Cancel();
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task started");

            // Searching here.

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task finished");
        }, cts.Token);
    }
    catch
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }
}
```

On my code, tasks are canceled without it's started. I only see "Cancelled" line on debug console. I should cancel tasks because if I don't their numbers and app's CPU usage increases. Is there way to do that ?

Comment: Why do you assume a `Token` is valid after you called `cts.Cancel();`

Comment: So, why do you believe this code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rjGOZn - would print false.

Comment: Should i declare new CancellationTokenSource ?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: You keep using that cancellation token there... [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like Rand Random said, i should decleare `new CancellationTokenSource` object. I have edited my code like this and it's worked. Code should be like that:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
private async void TextBox1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    cts.Cancel();
    cts.Dispose();
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task started");

            // Searching here.

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task finished");
        }, cts.Token);
    }
    catch
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure you should dispose the old source.

Comment: I thought it would decrease memory usage.

Comment: Cancel doesn't happen immidiatly, so the Cancel doesn't wait for all tasks to be actually canceled and a task could still be running when you already disposed the CancellationTokenSource , so I would also say you shouldn't manually dispose it, but that is just a gut feeling without an evidence that I could provide. Let the garbage collector dispose it.

Comment: maybe `cts?.Cancel(); using(cts = new CancellationTokenSource()) { try {} catch {} cts = null; }` and declaration `CancellationTokenSource cts = null;`

Comment: @RandRandom GC doesn't call Dispose ...

Comment: @Selvin - here the last sentence fixed - Let the garbage collector finalize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make life easy for yourself, you should consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx)

I'm assuming you can write this method:

```
async Task<string[]> DoSearchAsync(string text, CancellationToken ct)
{
    /* you implement this method */
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
    private IDisposable _searchSubscription = null;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _searchSubscription =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern(h => TextBox1.TextChanged += h, h => TextBox1.TextChanged -= h)
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400.0))
                .Select(ep => TextBox1.Text)
                .Select(text => Observable.FromAsync(ct => DoSearchAsync(text, ct)))
                .Switch()
                .ObserveOn(TextBox1)
                .Subscribe(results => { /* update your UI */ });
    }
```

Now this watches your `TextChanged` event, waits 400.0 milliseconds in case you type another character - there's no sense firing off a load of searches if the user is still typing - and then it calls your new `DoSearchAsync` method.

Then it does a `Switch` which effectively means cancel any in-flight searchs and start this new one.

Finally it marshalls back to the UI thread and then gives you the results of the search so that you can update the UI.

It just handles all of the calling, background thread calls, marshalling back to the UI, all for you.

If you want to shut it down, just call `_searchSubscription.Dispose()`.

NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to get the bits.